# flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int?'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
E/flutter (12011): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int?'
E/flutter (12011): #0      new MyPostData.fromJson (package:demandium/feature/create_post/model/my_post_model.dart:144:5)
E/flutter (12011): #1      new Content.fromJson.<anonymous closure> (package:demandium/feature/create_post/model/my_post_model.dart:62:30)
E/flutter (12011): #2      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:416:8)
E/flutter (12011): #3      new Content.fromJson (package:demandium/feature/create_post/model/my_post_model.dart:61:20)
E/flutter (12011): #4      new PostModel.fromJson (package:demandium/feature/create_post/model/my_post_model.dart:18:39)
E/flutter (12011): #5      CreatePostController.getMyPostList (package:demandium/feature/create_post/controller/create_post_controller.dart:90:29)
E/flutter (12011): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter (12011): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int?'
E/flutter (12011): #0      new MyPostData.fromJson (package:demandium/feature/create_post/model/my_post_model.dart:144:5)
E/flutter (12011): #1      new Content.fromJson.<anonymous closure> (package:demandium/feature/create_post/model/my_post_model.dart:62:30)
E/flutter (12011): #2      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:416:8)
E/flutter (12011): #3      new Content.fromJson (package:demandium/feature/create_post/model/my_post_model.dart:61:20)
E/flutter (12011): #4      new PostModel.fromJson (package:demandium/feature/create_post/model/my_post_model.dart:18:39)
```

Comment: I'm new to the site. How to solve this problem?

Comment: it looks like there is a problem with your Model class (Post Model) parameter. While parsing, you are giving it a String value while it requires null or int as its value. So, you should either change the parameter type to String or you should give it an int value.

Comment: check your model, you are getting String in api but you are storing it in int.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I don't know how I should do this. Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Show your model code + api fetching method code + Api response code.